# Cannot implicitly convert List<T> to Collection<T>

Tags: c#, generics, collections

This is a compiler error (slightly changed for readability).

This one always puzzled me. FxCop tells that this is a bad thing to return `List<T>` and classes that are derived from `Collection<T>` should be preferable as return types.

Also, FxCop says that it is OK to use `List<T>` for internal data storage/manipulation. Ok, I get it, but what I don't get is why the compiler complains about trying to implicitly convert `List<T>` to `Collection<T>`. Isn't `List<T>` more interface-charged and functional? Why prohibit implicit conversion?

And another question that stems from above: is the `new List<int>(some collection<int>)` constructor expensive?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`List<T>` doesn't derive from `Collection<T>` - it does, however, implement `ICollection<T>`. That would be a better choice of return type.

As for the `new List<int>(some collection<int>)` question - it partly depends on what the collection is. If it implements `ICollection<T>` (at execution time) then the constructor can use its `Count` property to create the list with the right initial capacity before iterating through it and adding each item. If it doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` then it's just equivalent to:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
foreach (int x in otherCollection)
{
    list.Add(x);
}
```

Still nice to have in a convenient constructor, but not hugely efficient - it can't be, really.

I don't believe the constructor does anything cunning for arrays, which it potentially could - using `Array.Copy` or whatever to just copy the lot in one go rather than iterating though. (Likewise if it were another `List<T>` it could get at the backing array and copy that directly.)

Answer (score 111):

Why not just do the following:

```
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>(theList);
```

as Collection(IList input) takes a List as part of construction.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a generic extension method written in C# 3.0 used to convert `List<T>` to `Collection<T>`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>(this List<T> items)
    {
        Collection<T> collection = new Collection<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            collection.Add(items[i]);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

and it is used like this…

```
List<string> entities = new List<string>();
entities.Add("Value 1");
entities.Add("Value 2");
entities.Add("Value 3");
entities.Add("Value 4");

Collection<string> convertedEntities = entities.ToCollection<string>();
```

Answer (score 6):

`List<T>` doesn't inherit from `Collection<T>`.  Plain and simple.  Unless `List<T>` provides an operator to implicitly convert to/from `Collection<T>`, you can't do it. I would actually suggest returning `List<T>` if you can, as I believe the rules go something like this:

Accept as a parameter the least constrictive interface possible. 
Return as a return parameter the most constrictive type possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you convert from `List<T>` to `Collection<T>` (while using LINQ):

**The old function:**

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployee(int id)
{
     return ( from e in MyDataContext.Employees
                   select new Employee()
                   {
                     e.empId = id
                   }
             ).ToList();
}
```

**After conversion:**

```
using System.Collection.ObjectModel;

public Collection<Employee> GetEmployee(int id)
{
           return new Collection<Employee>( 
               (from e in MyDataContext.Employees
                     select new Employee()
                     {
                       e.empId = id
                     }
                ).ToList() as IList<Employee>
           );
}
```

Comment: as IList<Employee> save my day thanks @Shadi Namrouti

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the below

```
public class EmployeeCollection : Collection<Employee>
{
      public EmployeeCollection(IList<Employee> list) : base(list)
      {}

      public EmployeeCollection() : base()
      {}

}
```

Use the class like this

```
EmployeeCollection  employeeCollection = new EmployeeCollection(list)
```

Answer (score -2):

The other way around, it is not necessary to loop... you can make just `.ToList()`

```
    ICollection<T> collection = new Collection<T>();
```

fill your collection using any method, and when you need the list, just do this:

```
    List<T> list = collection.ToList();
```

after that you can use whatever you want with your list.

Have a good coding!