# Convert List<Cookie> to CookieCollection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

Let's say I have `List<Cookie>` and I want to convert it to a `CookieCollection`. What's the easiest way to do this?

I know I can use a foreach loop, but isn't there a way to instantiate it with code similar to this?

```
List<Cookie> l = ...;
var c = new CookieCollection() { l };
```

When I try to compile that though, I get the error:

> The best overloaded Add method
>   'System.Net.CookieCollection.Add(System.Net.CookieCollection)'
>   for the collection initializer has
>   some invalid arguments

btw, there are two `Add` methods that `CookieCollection` supports:

```
public void Add(Cookie cookie);
public void Add(CookieCollection cookies);
```

Comment: Does CookieCollection have a constructor that takes an IEnumerable<Cookie> or ICollection<Cookie>?

Comment: You might consider looking at this (potentially) [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524428/cannot-implicitly-convert-listt-to-collectiont).

Comment: This isn't a Collection<T> though, it implements ICollection.

Comment: No, the only constructor takes no parameters.

Comment: The answer in that question actually covers if it's Collection<T> or ICollection, and it's the same response you marked as the answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CookieCollection was written before .Net 2 (before Generics). Therefore, there's really no quick nice way to do it other than manually with a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why there is no quick way to do it.

Comment: You don't have to manually use a C# foreach loop if you use the List<T>.ForEach(..) method Paul Creasey posted in his answer.

Comment: @jdk: That's still a foreach loop just with different syntax.

Answer (score 8):

Given `c` and `l` as in your first example, this'll do:

```
l.ForEach(c.Add);
```

Comment: didn't realise you could skip the lambda, nice.

Comment: well yes `x => y(x)` is just shorthand for "a function that takes x, and does y with it", and since `c.Add` meets that description as well, you can pass that function just as your rather-anonymously-typed-lambda =) 'tis neat

Comment: Interesting shortcut. Too bad you can't mark two answers as accepted. In this case though, I was a bit more interested as to why I couldn't initialize it with that form, so I accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a lambda to the ForEach method of a List.  This will work independent of the constructors of the CookieCollection.

```
List<Cookie> l = ...;
var c = new CookieCollection();
l.ForEach(tempCookie => c.Add(tempCookie));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Cookie> l = ...;
var c = new CookieCollection();
l.ForEach(x => c.Add(x));
```

Comment: C# 3.x and using System.Collections.Generic;