# Unable to cast an object of type "object {System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>}" as ICollection<object>

Tags: c#, .net

Why can you not cast a object which at runtime has type `object {System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>}` as an `ICollection<object>`?

I'm sure its something obvious but I cant figure it out.

It gives the exception -

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String[]]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Object]'.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524428/cannot-implicitly-convert-listt-to-collectiont

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before C# 4.0, generics are not covariant. If you are not using C# 4.0, you can accomplish this cast like this:

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
//...Fill the list...
ICollection<object> collection = list.ConvertAll<object>(item => item as object);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Variance in Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx)