# In C# can you up-cast an object type to a collection type of generic "object"s

Tags: c#, types, casting, type-conversion, covariance

Disclaimer after getting downvoted:

We did find a solution, with additional wisdom on why this is a smelly predicament to find yourself in. Many thanks to the community.

The original problem, in short, was that `myObject` was of type `object`, cast-able to `HashSet<Availability>` in one case, but cast-able to `HashSet<Contact>` in another case, etc, each instance a HashSet collection.

I wanted to iterate over the contents of the `myObject` collection, whether they were `Availability` objects, `Contact` objects, or something else.

Per the comments, you will see that the original question makes incorrect technical assumptions. I leave it below and unchanged as a learning opportunity for anyone who may have the same misunderstanding that I did.

Original question below:

---

I have an object of type `object` who, if I call `GetType()` on it, returns a type of `HashSet<Availability>` in one case, but returns an unrelated type of `HashSet<Contact>` in another case, or any number of as-yet unknown `HashSet<...>` types.

```
object myObject = getMyObject();
myObject.GetType() // = HashSet<Availability>
```

I would like to up-cast the object to a collection of some kind (HashSet or other) while down-casting the collection's generic type to an object so that the code does not have to know the as-yet unknown types at compile time.

```
object myObject = getMyObject();
myObject.GetType() // = HashSet<Availability>
var myUsefulObject = (HashSet<object>)myObject;
```

When I attempt this I am getting an "unable to cast..." exception.

Is this possible?
If so, how?

I believe I have covariance between the HashSet type that I have and the one I want, but because my *initial* type is only an object I am unable to do what [this stack-overflow answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682914/564406).

Comment: *Is this possible?* -- No. This is all a dream. The compiler isn't really telling you that your beliefs about covariance are wrong, and it's irrelevant that what you're doing is profoundly, fundamentally different from what's in that answer you linked.

Comment: Look, assume you could cast `HashSet<Availability>` to `HashSet<object>`. Then you could do this: `(new HashSet<Availability>() as HashSet<object>).Add("LOL")`. Does that look like a good idea to you?

Comment: Also, *why* would you want to do this? What's the end goal?

Comment: I usually find questions like this to be XY problems, what possible benefit is there to this sort of cast?

Comment: Thanks for the input! I do agree that it is not a great idea. Unfortunately, I have some troublesome delegates I am trying to work around. I am also quite aware that it *is* possible to mix strings and ints in a HashSet<object> using boxing. What am I missing? Perhaps the compiler simply can not do this conversion?

Comment: @David There is no `HashSet<object>` here. You have a `HashSet<Availability>`, which *is not* `HashSet<object>`. This question has nothing to do with `HashSet<object>`, because `HashSet<object>` and `HashSet<Availability>` are two completely unrelated classes which happen to have been generated the same way. I told you why the compiler won't do the conversion.

Comment: So ask about the delegates, not this. This is a workaround that smells bad! :)

Comment: *"because my initial type is only an object"* -- what "initial type" are you referring to? I think there are some wrong assumptions hidden in that statement. You can certainly create a new `HashSet<object>` which contains all the objects contained in an existing `HashSet<Availability>`. But if you show us what you are trying to do with this thing, we may be able to find a better way. If you can redefine the delegates, lots of possibilities open up.

Comment: Note that `(HashSet<object>)myObject` does not convert `myObject`. It is only like a pair of colored glasses making you look at the **same** `HashSet<Availability>` object in a different way. Behind the scenes nothing has changed. Well, that's how it would be, if you were able to cast.

Comment: How do you know that `getMyObject()` returns a `HashSet<Availability>`? if it does, then why not change the code to `HashSet<Availability> myObject = getMyObject()`? If you know what the method returns, declare your variable as that type. If you don't know what it returns then there's no real reason to call the function. IOW, declare everything according to expected types and don't use `object`. Don't solve the problem, make it disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! I will stew on this for a bit and perhaps ask from a different angle with more info. @EdPlunkett and @ScottHannen, when `myObject` is returned it is returned as only a base `object` type, cast-able to `HashSet<Availability>` in one case, but cast-able to `HashSet<Contact>` in another case, etc. I was hoping to deal with it as a `HashSet<object>` to make my problems go away. It is pretty painful code.

Comment: Note that you can cast your set to for example `IReadOnlyCollection<object>`. This might or might not be enough to achieve your goal.

Comment: Try using generics instead perhaps, all depends on what your're going to be doing with the HashSet.

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully make it a little more clear. The code I am working with is pretty painful, as many of you easily spotted. @Evk, your suggestion works! That is enough! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. You may have just helped me do something terrible on the day after Christmas ;). Though, I will still see if I can get the code reworked so this type finagling is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you all again for your help. I felt pretty pummeled on this one, but at the same time quite grateful to get so much help from so many people. You guys are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long chain of comments under your question shows - you cannot cast `HashSet<Availability>` to `HashSet<object>`, because there is just no implicit\explicit\any other conversion defined between those two types. However, `HashSet<T>` implements several covariant interfaces, such as `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, and you can cast `HashSet<Availability>` to those interfaces (of `object`):

```
object myObject = getMyObject();
var myUsefulObject = (IReadOnlyCollection<object>)myObject;
```

If type `T` is covariant in interface - this type cannot be used as argument in any method in that interface and can only be used as return type. That means all methods which might break type-safety in this case (such as `Add(T item)`, `Remove(T item)` and so on) cannot be present in such interface, and returning `Availability` as `object` is not a problem.

Comment: This is beautiful. 
`object propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(baseModel);                           
                            if (propValue is IEnumerable o)
                            {
                                object result = ((IReadOnlyCollection<object>)o).First();`