# Get Collection of Other Class using generic Collection class

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a collection class, let's say `UserCollection`, which is derived from `Collection` (base class for a generic collection).

Now I want a `UserCollection` and here is my code, but it is saying it can not convert from generic `List` to my collection class:

```
public class User
{
  // All user Fields
}

public class UserCollection : Collection<User>
{
   public static UserCollection GetUserCollection()
   {
       DataTable table = ...//all users data from DB
       List<User> userList = table.ToCollection<User>(); // Call an extension method to convert to          generic List of user
       return userList; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User>' to 'UserCollection'
   }
}
```

// ToCollection function is here

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/195889/Convert-Datatable-to-Collection-using-Generic

What do I need to make it work?

Comment: You have to loop the list again and `Add` each user one after the other to the `UserCollection`.

Comment: @Tim, so deriving from Collection doesn't gives me any additional benefits except providing Add/Remove etc functions ?

Comment: Why are you creating a new custom class instead of using, let's say, `List<T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide an appropriate constructor that calls the base constructor:

```
public class UserCollection : Collection<User>
{
    public UserCollection() { }
    public UserCollection(IList<User> users) : base(users) { }

    public static UserCollection GetUserCollection()
    {
        // ...
        List<User> userList = ... 
        return new UserCollection(userList);
    }
}
```

or you have to return  `ICollection<User>` instead because  `List<User>` is not a child class of `Collection<User>` or `UserCollection` but it implements `ICollection<User>`.

Here is a related question: [Cannot implicitly convert List<T> to Collection<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524428/cannot-implicitly-convert-listt-to-collectiont)

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons this will not work.  Primarily, you cannot cast a class to an inherited class.  UserCollection is a Collection, but Collection is not a UserCollection.  You could assign UserCollection to a Collection variable but no the other way around.  Additionally, you are receiving a List from the ToCollection method.  You run into the same scenario: Collection<> is not a List<>.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx for more information about casting.

One solution is to implement a constructor that calls the base constructor that takes an IList<> like so:

```
public UserCollection(IList<User> users)
    : base(users)
{
}
```

Then you could modify your GetUserCollection method to call it:

```
public static UserCollection GetUserCollection()
{
   DataTable table = ...//all users data from DB
   List<User> userList = table.ToCollection<User>(); 
   return new UserCollection(userList);
}
```

Comment: Darn, I was beaten to the punch.